# Selectively use dependent modules in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm writing a small application where I have all AngularJS code inside of one file. This file is included in every HTML page. How would I filter which dependent modules are needed for specific HTML page? I.e. if I have e.g.:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngTouch', 'ngMessages']);
```

but I only need `ngTouch` on some pages and on the other pages only `ngMessages`, how would I prevent loading the other, unnecessary dependent module for each page?

Answer (score 0):

You would use specialized modules to depend on a core module to separate the concerns. So for example, you could have something similar to this:

```
angular.module('app.core', ['ngAnimate']);
angular.module('PicadviceApp', ['app.core', 'ngTouch']);
angular.module('messages', ['app.core', 'ngMessages']);
```

This would essentially declare the 'app.core' module as the core module that every page in your application needs to load, and on specific pages you would then have specialized modules that load any additional dependencies.

One page can load up the PicadviceApp module and another page would load up the messages module. But both pages would have access to the ngAnimate module because of the app.core dependency.

Comment: Yes, I thought of doing it like so, but is this the "correct" way of using modules? They should represent parts of application functionalities, not to group dependent modules... And if going this way, I would have to have a separate .js file for every page, but like I said, I want to have everything in a single .js file.

Comment: Yes, each module should encapsulate whatever they are responsible for. If you have cross-application concerns then you would have all that logic within that one module (app.core). Feature areas can definitely be in their own modules but you also wouldn't want to duplicate any logic across each feature. Check out a style guide I prefer here:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y164